# Sort list by property/anonymous function?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, overloading

I've got a list defined like this...

```
var sets = new List<HashSet<int>>(numSets);
```

Why isn't there an overload so I can sort it like this?

```
sets.Sort(s => s.Count);
```

I want the largest set first. What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `List<T>` class was introduced in .NET 2.0 and the designers of this class decided so. You could use the [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) extension method:

```
sets = sets.OrderByDescending(s => s.Count).ToList();
```

Comment: This will sort in ascending order. The OP wants the largest set first. You need `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: @Ani, correct. I've updated my post to reflect this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Both solutions look good... I'm going to wait to see who gets more votes before I choose :P Thanks! I like how easy this one is to read.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sets.Sort((setA, setB) => setB.Count.CompareTo(setA.Count));
```

This uses the `Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)` overload of `List<T>.Sort`.
The fact that the expression compares B with A rather than A with B is what produces the descending-by-count order that you require.

The reason your code doesn't work is because `List<T>.Sort`, unlike `Enumerable.OrderByDescending`, does not have an overload that accepts a `Func<TSource, TKey>` key-selector.

@Darin Dimitrov's technique of using `OrderByDescending` is fine too, but note that this will create a sorted list out of place and reassign the reference you have to the original list to the new, sorted one.

Comment: Oh...so there is an anonymous function overload. I saw that `Comparison<>` thing, but I didn't know what it was.

Comment: Reassigning is fine... but which is more efficient? I'd guess this one because it does it in-place. OTH, his reads more like English.

Comment: @Mark: The in-place one *should* be more efficient. Of course, the only way to find out is by measuring. I agree with you on the readability point. To get the best of both solutions, you might want to consider writing an extension method for `List<T>` with a key-selector parameter.